# onbeforeunload is calling after every page open

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an issue with onbeforeunload. I just want to delete some tables' data after closing browser. Its working with all browser, however its not working with IE. When I working in IE, if I go to another link, onbeforeunload function executes, but other browser only execute after closing.

my code is

```
<script language="javascript">
function fnUnloadHandler() {
xmlhttp=null; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
  {// code for Firefox, Opera, IE7, etc. 
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
 {// code for IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
 } 

if (xmlhttp!=null) 
 {  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://yourhost/del_cart_actionFile.php",true); 
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
 } 
 else 
 { 
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP."); 
 } 
}
</script>
 <body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()">
</body>
```

please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com), it is based on javascript, it handles all these browser incompatibilities for you.

Comment: but why IE is not acting like any other browser. All the browser working good with this code.

Comment: Nobody told you? IE is a nightmare for web-developers.